# How to connect a NavLink to another component on the same page (React)?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a one-page React website with 6 components. At the top of the page I have a Bootstrap NavBar, and I want to connect the nav links to their respective components. Basically I'd like them to function as anchor links would in HTML - to scroll down to the relevant component when clicked.

These are my nav links right now. I've done a lot of searching and have found a lot of different info/answers, so don't really know where to start.

```
<Nav className="mx-auto Nav nav-links">
  <Nav.Link href="#">Clases</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="#">Estudio</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="#">Tu Instructora</Nav.Link>
  <Nav.Link href="#">Contacto</Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

Comment: These links don't link to any content. Can you [edit] to share a more complete [mcve] that includes the React components/page sections you want to link to?

Answer (score 0):

Use [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) library that you can use Link and Element for handling smooth scrolling easily :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be worked out of the box if you have nodes with corresponding ids.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-b1erif?file=App.tsx,index.tsx

But for more useful features like smooth scrolling and positioning, you can use `react-scroll`.